# Splitting a string after the last space

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Iam making a program that syncs to a DB, and it takes in names, so i want to split the parsed in string into 2 strings after the last "space".

e.g. splitting the name "John Doe Jackson" into:
john Doe and Jackson

so far what ive done i getting the last name:

```
public static string getLastName(string fullname)
{
    string lastName = fullname.Split(' ').LastOrDefault();
}
```

how to return the rest of the string so i have something like:

> firstName: John Doe
>
> lastName: Jackson

---

EDIT: made it by doing it like this, isnt the cleanest way, but it gets the job done!

```
     public static string getLastName(string fullname)
    {
        string lastName = fullname.Split(' ').LastOrDefault();
        Console.WriteLine(lastName);
        return lastName;
    }

    public static string getFirstName(string fullname)
    {
        var parts = fullname.Split(' ');
        var lastName = parts.LastOrDefault();
        var firstName = string.Join(" ", parts.Take(parts.Length - 1));
        return firstName;
    }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var parts = fullname.Split(' ');
var lastName = parts.LastOrDefault();
var firstName = string.Join(" ",parts.Take(parts.Length-1));
```

Comment: Used this in my code, but realized that in the case of no spaces in "fullname" the "lastName" will contain the "fullName" and "firstName" will be empty. Also just one space at the begining of the string.

Comment: @Riga This would work only when you string has the format  "John Doe Jackson". It address this problem. If the are no spaces in the fullName another logic (custom to the specific format should be applied).

Comment: very nice answer. +1

Answer (score 6):

I'd do:

```
var lastSpaceIndex = fullName.LastIndexOf(' ');
var firstName = fullName.Substring(0, lastSpaceIndex);
var lastName = fullName.Substring(lastSpaceIndex+1);
```

[See it in action here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jpRKQQ)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string.Join`

```
public static string getFirstName(string fullname)
{
    return string.join(" ",fullname.Split(' ').Take(fullname.Split(' ').Count()-1));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another version based on accepted answer but protecting for string null/empty and in case of no spaces in fullName leaving input as firstName

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fullName))
     return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(string.Empty, string.Empty);

var parts = fullName.Trim().Split(' ');
if (parts.Length == 1)
     return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(parts[0], string.Empty);

var firstName = string.Join(" ", parts.Take(parts.Length - 1));
var lastName = parts.LastOrDefault();

return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(firstName, lastName);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string name = "John Doe Jackson";
var names = name.Split(' ');
string firstname = names[0] + " " + names[1];
string lastname = names[2];
```

Comment: This scenario does not work in where middle name, not found